# angular fetch web api data ( in browser network tab it fetch data with 200 ok response) but data not displaying

Tags: angular

angular fetch web api data and in browser network tab it fetch data with 200 ok response but data not displaying.Table also making equal row as data source row but everytimes it gives empty value.Here is my code:

```
 ///////////   Model.ts:

               export interface Menue 
                {
                 Id:number;
                 Name:string;
                  Price:number;
                    Details:string;
                                      }
//////////   Menue.Service.ts:

                    export class MenueService {

                        Url='http://localhost:61362/api/Menue';
                      constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

                     getMenue():Observable<Menue[]>{

                        return this.http.get<Menue[]>(this.Url);
                                                       }
                                                   }

  /////////////  Menue.Component.ts:

           public menues=[];
          ngOnInit() {

      this.service.getMenue().subscribe(data => this.menues = data);

                    }     
     ////////// Menue.html:

         <tr *ngFor="let men of menues">  
         <td>{{men.Id}}</td>  
           <td>{{men.Name}}</td>  
         <td>{{men.Price}}</td>  
      <td>{{men.Details}}</td>  

        </tr>
```

Comment: Are you seeing any error browser devtool?

Comment: no, there is no error @Ansuman

Comment: Can you do a console.log(data) inside your subscribe method and see if you are actually getting data?

Comment: yes.I,m getting data in console @Ansuman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I was wrong, you have seen the console.log(), in another nvaigator that it´s not Chrome, for example Mozilla.

Your response is correctly.

only fix this.
You have capitalize in your response is lowecase

```
     <tr *ngFor="let men of menues">  
             <td>{{men.Id}}</td>   // {{men.id}}
               <td>{{men.Name}}</td>  // {{men.name}}
             <td>{{men.Price}}</td>  // {{men.price}}
          <td>{{men.Details}}</td>  // no see in your response, but i can imagine that exists in the response

            </tr>
```

/*
* In your response is lowercase
*/
    Object { **id**: 1, **name**: "65 TK lunch", **price**: 65, … }

Sorry my englishis very poor.
I hope to be helpfull.

Comment: Thanks,It works.I didn't see that too that response is in camelcase

Answer (score 0):

My english is very poor but try this

/*
* in this service
*/

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
     getMenue():Observable<Menue[]>{

          return this.http.get<Menue[]>(this.Url).pipe(map( resp =>{
            return resp;
         }));
                                                           }
  }
```

I hope to be helpfull.

Comment: returning the same result with empty data

Answer (score 0):

```
getMenue(){

              return this.http.get(this.Url).pipe(map( resp =>{
                    console.log("inside service",resp)
                return resp;
             }));
                                                               }
      }
```

Try this way if it´s empty, that url no return data,  if contains some information can see the structure.

Can you show the tab network response in Chrome?

Comment: I.m getting data in console but not displaying in html page

Comment: Can you put the response in console, please and the interface or class Menue.

Comment: i put response in console and in console i get data but data isnot displaying

Comment: Can you put your response, that you can see, when you use this service please?

Comment: If you recieved the info, can you shared? So I see the best way for solve yhis issue.

Comment: ​I get these json data in console:
2: Object { id: 3, name: "100 TK dinner", price: 100, … }
​
3: Object { id: 1005, name: "val", price: 90, … }
​
4: Object { id: 1006, name: "d", price: 9, … }
​
5: Object { id: 1007, name: "c", price: 20, … }

Answer (score 0):

I see, the backend no response un array correctly, the answer or response similar this,

```
Food
Array(n)// number of results
0:{ id: 3, name: "100 TK dinner", price: 100, … }, 1:{ id: 1005, name: "val", price: 90, … },​2: { id: 1006, name: "d", price: 9, … }
```

The easy solution it´s put this informatin into array, when you create the new object response, push into array this response, for build the correctly array.

There are possibility for see estructure response the backend.

Comment: i'm getting data in console in this format:  ​ 
0: Object { id: 1, name: "65 TK lunch", price: 65, … }
​
1: Object { id: 2, name: "120 TK lunch", price: 120, … }
​
2: Object { id: 3, name: "100 TK dinner", price: 100, … }
​
3: Object { id: 1005, name: "val", price: 90, … }
​
4: Object { id: 1006, name: "d", price: 9, … }
​
5: Object { id: 1007, name: "c", price: 20, … }
​
6: Object { id: 1008, name: "zxxcf", price: 120, … }

Comment: i'm just confused about what to do .here is my method:                                                                                                                                       getMenue() {
                              return this.http.get(this.url).subscribe(  
     data => {  
      this.menue = data as [],
                                        console.log(data);  
                                         }
                                          );
                                              }